# Fix up [fixed-point]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

[fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point) refers to two almost completely unrelated concepts:

- [Fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), a pragmatic (sometimes even hacky) implementation of approximate real numbers, mostly relevant as an optimisation of numerical performance in memory-constrained applications.
- Fixpoint combinators and the [fixpoints of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) which they find. These are of high theoretical interest, considered very elegant, but have rather fewer real-world applications and are often arguably better replaced with more mundane loop constructs if *performance* is a concern.

I'd suggest splitting this tag in two unambiguous ones: <strike>[fixed-precision] for fixed-point arithmetic</strike> and [fixpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoints) for fixed-point combinators.

Comment: On a more serious note, correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the fixed point arithmetic questions be retagged to [tag:precision]?

Comment: I think [tag:precision] is a lot more general than [tag:fixed-point].

Comment: Well yeah, but do we really need [tag:fixed-precision] *and* [tag:precision]?

Comment: Yes. [tag:fixed-precision] would be a lot about performance, memory and overflow issues, which have nothing to do with precision (nor with fixpoints).

Comment: Fixed point arithmetic at it's core is directly related to mathematical precision, which is what the [tag:precision] tag is about. If performance is a concern, there is the [tag:performance] tag. Note though that if we get rid of [tag:fixed-point] then [tag:floating-point] will have to go as well. We might as well just leave fixed-point as it is and make a new tag for fixpoints, or [tag:fixed-point-combinators]

Comment: I like @TinyGiant's suggestion of fixed-point-combinators... People who ask about theoretical functional programming would easily recognize the proper tag, the rest will use most likely more appropriate "fixed-point".

Comment: Not sure about fixpoint combinators, but if fixed-point arithmetic doesn't have a [fixed-point] tag, no one will get their questions about it tagged correctly. Nothing else is discoverable. [fixed-precision] is a rather lousy tag because it's not what everyone calls it.

Comment: (1) I have just carried out the disambiguation, creating [tag:fixpoint-combinators] in the process. I plan to add it to other relevant questions over the following days. [tag:fixed-point-combinators] will (hopefully) [become a synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386935/). (2) Up to now, I haven't bothered with separating questions about `fix` and friends from questions about `Fix` and friends. Do you think that would be worth the trouble?

Answer (score 4):

As per the comments, it seems to be not feasible to tag fixed-precision questions with anything else but [fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point), mainly because it's the obvious counterpart to [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point). Currently, these questions also make up a significant majority in in the [fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point) tag.

Therefore, the best thing would be to just remove fixpoint questions from that tag. Retag them as [fixpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoints) or [fixpoint-combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoint-combinator), and edit the tag wikis so it's clear which question should go where.

Answer (score 2):

I have carried out the disambiguation. In the process, [fixpoint-combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoint-combinators) (29 questions), [fixed-point-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-iteration) (24 questions), and [z3-fixedpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z3-fixedpoint) (13 questions) were created. Criticism and suggestions are welcome.

Below is the analysis I had previously done, upon which the changes were based.

---

[fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point) should be disambiguated. Its two main meanings are disjoint, and separating them should be straightforward, as the amount of fixed-point combinator questions under it is rather small (I estimate there are about forty of them). In addition, there are quite a few [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) questions about the `fix` function or the `Fix` type constructor not currently tagged [fixed-point] that would benefit from a disambiguated tag, and possibly the same goes for other language tags.

It should be mentioned there is a small handful of [fixed-point] questions not about either of the two main meanings. Up to now, I have seen:

- Questions about [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration), the algorithm from numerical analysis. (Example: [*Converting explicit euler to implicit euler (via fixed-point iteration)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54597447/2751851))
- Questions about the fixedpoint engine of the [z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z3) SMT solver. (Example: [*Changing order of Z3 fixepoint queries changes the result*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38594208/2751851))

I agree with the suggestions elsewhere in this discussion that [fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point) should be left for fixed-point arithmetic. For fixed-point combinators, I prefer [fixed-point-combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-combinators) (or perhaps [fixpoint-combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoint-combinators), if that is too much of a mouthful), as I don't feel [fixpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixpoint) is sufficiently disambiguating. Specific tags, such as [fixed-point-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-iteration) and [z3-fixedpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z3-fixedpoint), could also be created for the other meanings as appropriate.